# Android app widget not showing up in the List but works smoothly in Android 12 device

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-10.0, android-11, android-12

I have developed the widget following the official developer guide - [Make a Simple App Widget](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets), and It works as expected for Android 12 devices but fails in Android 11 - not in the listing, and QA team responded that the widget appears but is empty.
What could cause these?
please help if you are familiar with this.

THis is my appwidget-provider XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:description="@string/payment_app_widget_description"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/payment_app_widget"
android:initialLayout="@layout/payment_app_widget"
android:minWidth="264dp"
android:minHeight="@dimen/dimen_400dp"
android:previewImage="@drawable/payment_widget_preview"
android:updatePeriodMillis="@integer/mp_payment_app_widget_update_mili"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
tools:ignore="ResourceName" />
```

**//EDIT**

***When decreasing the minHeght to 300dp, it works for all devices.
PLease help me understand how to decide on what to provide as height, width.***

**//EDIT - 2**

***Actually The issue was something else. I had to set an image from URL to imgaview, and that I wad doing in the main thread only.
It worked for scenarios when the URL was empty.    SO the Fix was to the store the image already in the file, as the image was also used in other places, and use decodeBitmap(file) and set it into remote view.***

Comment: that's because android 12 support previewImage, and android 11 and below support previewLayout, add previewLayout attribute and if android sdk is android 11 it wall fall back automatically on previewLayout.

Comment: don't remove previewImage just add both, and things will work as expected

Comment: Yes @Mado, Agree with you.
At the moment, My query is how to correctly decide android:targetCellWidth and android:targetCellHeight and then minWidth and minHeight